# "Similar questions" are irrelevant to my questions when I don't add tags in question title

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, title

I've once been downvoted and told not to add any of the tags in my question title, but this makes the "Similar questions" that are displayed to be irrelevant to my question. Now, should the similar questions be designed to take tags into account or should I add the tags to my question title ?

EDIT:

My title : "**How to add a new option in an optionset dynamically ?**" - tags: **dynamics-crm2011**
In this case, the similar questions are not related to CRM.

I used to write my questions in this way: 
"In CRM 2011, how to add a new option to an optionset ? " - but I was told not to do this.

Comment: A title doesn't change the essence of a question, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Do those related questions have the `dynamics-crm2011` tag? Why do you care that much what questions are listed as related?

Comment: Questions need to be related by more than just the tag to be relevant as 'related questions'; to find questions about CRM 2011 is what tags are *for*; we don't need *all* CRM 2011 questions listed as related.

Comment: No, they don't have the crm 2011 tag. My point is, I need to simply see related questions while I'm writing my question for the sake of speed, I know I can search for it using my tags first in SO before writing my question, but then what's the use of "Similar questions" ?

Comment: Note that tags should be used for that list as well; if that's not happening, then that's a bug. See Jeff's answer in the related [Would it be feasible to tie the tags of a new question to the Related Questions list?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27566/would-it-be-feasible-to-tie-the-tags-of-a-new-question-to-the-related-questions) on MSE. (In which Ben S also proposes *"In order for users to know that their tags are involved in the Related Questions search, it may be more intuitive to place the tag input above the Related Questions list."*)

Comment: As for tags not being handled in that search: [Update suggestions when asking a question using tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213672/update-suggestions-when-asking-a-question-using-tags) on MSE.

Comment: @Arjan, that's exactly what I'm talking about. So I guess it's a bug, my tags are not affecting the related questions results.

Answer (score -6):

You should add tags to the tag field designed to take them. They will be automatically prepended to the question for SEO etc and should be taken in to account when filtering for possible duplicates and similar questions.

Had you filled in the tag box? If using the fields as suggested and you are not getting related similar questions then maybe your wording could be improved. Eg:

```
With title tags. Not recommended:
    "[Windows][XAMPP] Can't connect to server."

Without title tags. Very generic and inexact:
    "Can't connect to server."

Reworded:
    "Unable to establish connection to local XAMPP server running on Windows."
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've edited my questions to clarify more. What should be a correct title for the question under "Edit" ?

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking about. It explains why people frown upon the use of tags in the question title, sure, but that is not the question here.