# Does Stackoverflow use the tags at all to suggest/find similiar questions when typing question title

Tags: discussion

When asking a question, tags are the last fields that get populate before posting the question. I like the fact that when typing the question title, `Stackoverflow` suggests similar/related questions by searching against what is already being typed in the question title (or maybe question body too) as described in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891772/stackoverflow-related-questions-algorithm).

Assuming that existing workflow is as follow:

1. User types question title
2. SO suggests similar/related questions just beneath the question Title under **Questions that may already have your answer** section
3. User adds body to the question, SO suggests similar question to the right sidebar under **Similar Questions** section

Would it make any difference if the workflow was follow:

1. User provide tags first
2. User types question title
3. SO suggest similar/related questions based not only on question title but, also tags under **Questions that may already have your answer** section
4. User adds body to question, SO suggest similar question to the right sidebar under **Similar Questions** section

While the main purpose of tags are to filter/categorize questions, would it make any difference if  they are also used to suggest similiar questions before question is posted under **Questions that may already have your answer** section?

If using tags to suggest similar/related questions improve the suggestion list, then it could potentially reduce the number of duplicate questions in SO.

I am just curious whether use of tags along with question title make suggestion of similar/related questions any better?

Comment: This has been discussed many times before... The most relevant, and [possibly duplicate question is in the Related sidebar](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255319/similar-questions-are-irrelevant-to-my-questions-when-i-dont-add-tags-in-ques?rq=1), and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253305/) for example is a feature request to make the question-finding experience better.  Also on [the Meta Meta here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213672)...